# jQuery - Move surrounding <a> tag to after element

Tags: jquery

Been trying to figure this out for myself as it seems like it should be easy enough however it turns out I'm a bit of an idiot...

Basically I'm trying to move the contents of a specific 'a' tag to just outside itself and then move that 'a' tag to the end of the containing figure...

```
<figure class="myFigure">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="#">
  </a>
  <figcaption>Sample Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Change to...

```
<figure class="myFigure">
  <img src="#">
  <figcaption>Sample Caption</figcaption>
  <a href="#"></a>
</figure>
```

Note there is multiple instances of the above on a page, some with links and some without. I dont wish to effect the ones without a link.

To start off I've been trying variations of the following however this create multiples instances of each image within each figure...

```
$('.myFigure').each(function() {
    $('a',this).contents().insertBefore( 'figcaption' );
});
```

Regards
Ciarán

Comment: You want as a result an anchor with no content???

Comment: Yes exactly.. just the link. The link will be set to fill the area using CSS

Answer (score 1):

To get your expected result, you could use:

```
$('.myFigure').append(function() {
  return $(this).children('a').contents().unwrap().end();
});
```

Comment: Thank you A. Wolff. This works perfectly. So simple when you know how :)

Answer (score 1):

I acknowledge this is a far more 'procedural' method than A. Wolff's nice implementation. However as it seems you wanted to jig around all the elements - collecting them and then re-inserting them into the order you've specified can feel a little easier:

```
$('figure').each(function(){
    var $that   = $(this);
    var getimg  = $that.find( 'img' );
    var getLink = $that.find( 'a' );
    var getFig  = $that.find( 'figcaption' );
    $that.empty().append([ getimg, getFig, getLink ]);
});
```

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/hrhw1rxt/4/

Comment: Thank you MackieeE. This also works perfect and opens up a world of options! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below, I assumed that the link may contain other elements aside from images.

```js
$('figure > a').each(function() {
  var
    $this = $(this),
    $parent = $(this).closest('.myFigure');

  $this.children().insertBefore($this);
  $this.appendTo($parent);
})
```

```css
a {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure class="myFigure">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="#">
  </a>
  <figcaption>Sample Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```